# Does ActiveState PerlApp have a problem binding ico files as "Bound Files"

Tags: activestate, tkx, perlapp

I posted this question at ActiveState but got no reply from support or in a discussion forum. Here is probably better.

I'm a long time user of PerlApp (ver. 8.2.1 Build 292072) and I have experienced very few problems. But just recently, I've been creating a new Tkx app and hit a problem. Tkx allows ico files to be used in the application (replacing the Tk icon) and this works perfectly in development. But, when I have tried binding my ico file in "Bound Files" of PerlApp it refuses to work and the only way to get my app to run is by putting the original ico file in the same folder as the exe.

I have tried changing the name of the "Icon Sources" ico file, removing the "Icon Sources" ico file completely, but the "Bound Files" ico file refuses to be bound.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was related to how I was referencing the external bound file within the program. I needed to use the following line of code,:

```
$iconfile = PerlApp::extract_bound_file("bound_icon_filename");
```

Everything worked fine after this.